# Tried retrieving values from a table with WebDriver, but the output displays the same value twice

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Duplicate values are shown, i.e. each table value is shown twice.

```
@Test
public void drpdownval() {
  driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("selenium");
  WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_m"));
  List<WebElement> trow = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  for (WebElement rowtext : trow) {
    System.out.println(rowtext.getText());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you referenced

```
List<WebElement> trow = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

has `<TR>` tag name, you have to find instances of that in the loop and put duplicate references off.

The table has two rows `<tr>`.

Then you are going to loop

```
int count=0;
for (WebElement rowtext : trow) {
  count++;
  System.out.println(rowtext.getText());
}
System.out.println(count);
```

and output should be `2`.